# Fails with Health check error in GCP composer using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I was trying to create a Cloud Composer in GCP using terraform. I was using the terraform version Terraform v0.12.5. But i am unable to launch an instance using terraform.

I am getting the following error

```
Error: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting for Creating Environment: Error code 3, message: Http error status code: 400
Http error message: BAD REQUEST
Additional errors:
    {"ResourceType":"appengine.v1.version","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Legacy health checks are no longer supported for the App Engine Flexible environment. Please remove the 'health_check' section from your app.yaml and configure updated health checks. For instructions on migrating to split health checks see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-to-split-health-checks","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[],"statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/qabc39fc336994cc4-tp/services/default/versions","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

main.tf

```
    resource "google_composer_environment" "sample-composer" {
      provider= google-beta
      project = "${var.project_id}"
      name    = "${var.google_composer_environment_name}"
      region  = "${var.region}"
      config {
        node_count = "${var.composer_node_count}"

        node_config {
          zone         = "${var.zone}"
          disk_size_gb = "${var.disk_size_gb}"
          machine_type = "${var.composer_machine_type}"
          network      = google_compute_network.xxx-network.self_link
          subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.xxx-subnetwork.self_link
        }
        software_config {
          env_variables = {
              AIRFLOW_CONN_SAMPLEMEDIA_FTP_CONNECTION = "ftp://${var.ftp_user}:${var.ftp_password}@${var.ftp_host}"
        }
          image_version  = "${var.composer_airflow_version}"
          python_version = "${var.composer_python_version}"
        }
      }
    }

resource "google_compute_network" "sample-network" {
  name    = "composer-xxx-network"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "sample-subnetwork" {
  name          = "composer-xxx-subnetwork"
  project       = "${var.project_id}"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  region        = "${var.region}"
  network       = google_compute_network.xxx-network.self_link
}
```

variables.tf

```
# Machine specific information for creating Instance in GCP

variable "project_id" {
  description = "The name of GCP project"
  default = "sample-test"
}

variable "google_composer_environment_name" {
  description = "The name of the instance"
  default = "sample-analytics-dev"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "The name of GCP region"
  default = "europe-west1"
}

variable "composer_node_count" {
  description = "The number of node count"
  default = "3"
}

variable "zone" {
  description = "The zone in which instance to be launched"
  default = "europe-west1-c"
}

variable "disk_size_gb" {
  description = "The machine size in GB"
  default = "100"
}

variable "composer_machine_type" {
  description = "The type of machine to be launched in GCP"
  default = "n1-standard-1"
}

# Environmental Variables

variable "ftp_user" {
  description = "Environmental variables for FTP user"
  default = "test"
}

variable "ftp_password" {
  description = "Environmental variables for FTP password"
  default = "4444erf"
}

variable "ftp_host" {
  description = "Environmental variables for FTP host"
  default = "sample.logs.llnw.net"
}

# Versions for Cloud Composer, Aiflow and Python

variable "composer_airflow_version" {
  description = "The composer and airflow versions to launch instance in GCP"
  default = "composer-1.7.2-airflow-1.10.2"
}

variable "composer_python_version" {
  description = "The version of python"
  default = "3"
}

# Network information

variable "composer_network_name" {
  description = "Environmental variables for FTP user"
  default = "composer-xxx-network"
}

variable "composer_subnetwork_name" {
  description = "Environmental variables for FTP user"
  default = "composer-xxx-subnetwork"
}
```

Creating Composer on GCP platform works without any issues. When creating using terraform it requires a health check.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your current user case within my GCP cloudshell [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) binary and so far no issue occurred, [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) environment has been successfully created:

```
$ terraform -v                                                                                                                                                                                          
Terraform v0.12.9
+ provider.google v3.1.0
+ provider.google-beta v3.1.0
```

A few concerns from my side:

The issue you've reported might be relevant to the usage of legacy health checks, which are essentially deprecated and replaced by [split health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks):

> As of September 15, 2019, if you're using the legacy health checks,
>   your application will continue to run and receive health checks but
>   you won't be able to deploy new versions of your application.

You've not specified any info part about your Terraform GCP [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html) version and I suppose that issue can be hidden there, as I've seen in this [Changelog](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google-beta/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-beta1-november-15-2019) that `split_health_checks` are enabled in `google_app_engine_application.feature_settings` since `3.0.0-beta.1` has been released.

Feel free to add some more insights in order to support you resolving the current issue.

Comment: I am getting same error with google provider 3.3.0 any hint?

Comment: Did you get the same error building composer on the default Cloud composer [version](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions)?

Comment: Have you got the same results, building composer environment via `gcloud` or GCP console?

Comment: Was getting the same error even using gcloud directly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428114/gcp-composer-creation-failed-with-bad-request/59527854#59527854

Comment: Hope that issue has been resolved for you according to the link provided, as @itroulli suggested in the answer.