# GCP composer creation failed with bad request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

Trying to create GCP composer environment instance with gcloud CLI

```
gcloud composer environments create "jakub" \
>     --project "projectX" \
>     --location "us-central1" \
>     --zone "us-central1-a" \
>     --disk-size 50GB \
>     --node-count 3 \
>     --image-version composer-1.7.1-airflow-1.10.2 \
>     --machine-type n1-standard-2 \
>     --python-version 3 \
>     --labels env="test"
```

After an hour getting error:

```
f7b3f4-6b95-4fb0-85e3-f39a2b11cec9] failed: Http error status code: 400
Http error message: BAD REQUEST
Additional errors:
    {"ResourceType":"appengine.v1.version","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Legacy health checks are no longer supported for the App Engine Flexible environment. Please remove the 'health_check' section from your app.yaml and configure updated health checks. For instructions on migrating to split health checks see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating-to-split-health-checks","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[],"statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/vd41e6cad4ccb2a7b-tp/services/default/versions","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

Based on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/create

Comment: I believe that this is an internal error, Airflow webserver deployment seems to have failed (AppEngine flex + `vd41e6cad4ccb2a7b-tp` looks like the name of a Cloud Composer AppEngine appspot). Could you try with the latest version available (`composer-1.8.3-airflow-1.10.3`) (not sure if that fixes the issue though but it's worth trying)? Otherwise, I believe you can create an issue on Google Public Issue Tracker because your command seems valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because you are trying to use an old image version. Retry Composer Environment creation with a newer supported version as per [Supported Cloud Composer versions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#new_environments).

Comment: I was getting the same error even without a version specified -> using latest

Comment: @jaksky The "Additional errors" field was also identical? Could you try again either by not specifying an image version or by specifying one from the list a linked in my answer and post the full error message?
Sidenote: when you don't specify an image-version, the default is not the latest but "composer-1.8.3-airflow-1.9.0" as you can see on the table.

Comment: Thx, you are correct. Sorry that I overlooked it at first